# When C2 axis of symmetry is present then is the compound meso?

Tags: organic-chemistry, optical-properties

If suppose a compound has C2 axis of symmetry then is it confirmed that the compound will be meso or it can have an enantiomeric pair? And which of following conditions are sufficient enough to declare a compound meso:- Plane of symmetry, Centre of symmetry, axis of symmetry and alternate axis of symmetry?